# How to find a column with missing value in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with 200 columns. All cells would be having only 3 possible characters. I want to find out the columns which don't have all 3 characters (in any sequence, in any repetition). Lets say, if any of the character is missed in Column, formula should mark that in the cell below.

Sorry, I am not an excel guy and this is needed to put a check in some 200 such long workbooks.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use a separate sheet, in which you shadow all the cells. For each cell you check if the corresponding cell on the other sheet is valid. If it is you show `0`, if it isn't, you show `1`. Now sum all the columns and if the sum is higher than `0` then the column is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Is the formatting of your spreadsheet maybe something you can use to identify the items which are not compliant since colour is much easier way to get a grand overview of problems in a lot of data.

If you can, how about stepping through each cell in that range and using 3 Instr function to find the cells with all 3 values you want.

I will assume you are looking for A, B and C as your 3 values for the purpose of the below code.

```
MyCell=cells(MyRow,MyColumn)
MatchCharA="A"
MatchCharB="B"
MatchCharC="C"

CheckA=instr(1,MyCell,MatchCharA)
CheckB=instr(1,MyCell,MatchCharB)
CheckC=instr(1,MyCell,MatchCharC)

If CheckA>0 then CharExist=1 else CharExist=0
If CheckB>0 then CharExist=CharExist+1
If CheckC>0 then CharExist=CharExist+1
```

Now you can use the variable CharExist which will return either:-
0 if there is no match in the cell
1 if 1 char exist in the cell, 2 if 2 characters exist in the cell or 3 if all the characters exist in the cell.

Finally you can use

```
Cells(MyRow, MyColumn).Font.Color = RGB(0, 51, 204)
```

to colour the cells maybe green, yellow or red depending on the CharExist value.

Just remember all the above code should be in your loop which steps through each cell of one column after another, and you must remember to reset the CheckA, CheckB, CheckC back to 0 at the end or beginning of each loop cycle to ensure that the previous cells value do not influence the next result in CharExist.

I hope this helps as I have a tendency to over explain so please forgive me if I gave more detail than what you needed.